# Access method of extended type in Go

Tags: oop, inheritance, go

The follow codes produces "prog.go:17: c.Test undefined (type Child has no field or method Test)". (http://play.golang.org/p/g3InujEX9W)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Base struct {
    X int
}

func (b Base) Test() int {
    return b.X
}

type Child Base

func main() {
    c := Child{4}
    fmt.Println(c.Test())
}
```

I realize `Test` is technically defined on `Base`, but should `Child` inherit that method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the way to go for inheritance in go is using `struct embedding` with `anonymous struct members`.
[Here is an adaption of your example](http://play.golang.org/p/CNGROmVc-_).

Read about struct embedding and go's approach to inheritance etc [here](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.de/2011/06/anonymous-fields-in-structs-like-object.html)

The behaviour you encountered is expected and in sync with the [golang specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), which explicitly states that:

> The method set of any type T consists of all methods with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T). Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields, as described in the section on struct types. **Any other type has an empty method set.**

Comment: I switched it to embedded struct for testing while waiting for some help here and figured that was the only way to accomplish what I wanted. Was just hoping (and kind of expected) the behavior I described. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify, that the behaviour you encountered is a direct result of the language specification. Glad I could help. Happy coding :-)